# Mongoose population issue at the second level

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to populate more than one field in a mongodb using mongoose, but it keeps causing server error
I use mongodb, mongoose, nodejs, and express latest versions.
I use local mongodb server and it works fine
here's the code

User schema

```
//User schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  profilePicture: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  categories: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
  ],
});

//Users collection
module.exports = new mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

Todo schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  important: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
  },
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
```

category shcema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
});

categorySchema.index({ name: 1, user: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = new mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

the call

```
app.get("/list/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let list = await Todo.find()
      .populate("category")
      .populate("user")
      .exec((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error", error: err });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({ results });
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error", error: err });
  }
});
```

the response

```
{
    "message": "Server error",
    "error": {}
}
```

When i use populate("category") only it works but when i use both category and user it makes server error

I tried

```
.populate("category user")
```

```
.populate({"category", "user"})
```

Comment: Perhaps make the error messages slightly different so you can tell which one is being executed.  For the response in the catch, try return `err.message`

Answer (score 0):

the operation populate only accept 1 parameter, «String|Object|Array»
[document_Document-populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate)

and this is not a valid object: `{"category", "user"}`

to populate multiple path, you should put them in an array

```
.populate(["category", "user"])
```

or, call populate multiple times

```
.populate("category")
.populate("user")
```

since you are using `async` function, you can optimize the code to be:

```
const results = await Todo.find()
      .populate("category")
      .populate("user")
      .exec()
return res.json({ results });
```